# Probability of n uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let U_1, U_2, . . . be independent random variables all uniformly distributed on
the unit interval, and let N be the first integer n ≥ 2 such that U_n > U_n−1.

Show that for each real number 0 ≤ u ≤ 1,
P(U1 ≤ u and N = n) = (u^(n−1))/(n−1)! − u^n/n

I had some questions about what I can even assume when starting this problem.  Are U_1<=u and N=n independent events?  And what does it mean for N to equal n?  Just needed some advice on how to start thinking about the problem!

Answer (score 1):

1. Formally $U_1, U_2, \ldots$ are functions $: \Omega \to [0, 1]$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, P)$ is a probability space. Then $N : \Omega \to \{ 2, 3, 4, \ldots \}$ is also a random variable given by

   $$N(\omega) = \min \{ n \geqslant 2 : U_n(\omega) > U_{n-1}(\omega) \}.$$

   Now for a fixed $n \geqslant 2$

   $$P( U_1 \leqslant u \ \& \ N = n ) := P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : U_1(\omega) \leqslant u \ \& \ N(\omega) = n \} ).$$
2. The events $U_1 \leqslant u$ and $N = n$ don't seem independent. If $n = 2$ and $u$ is very small, the probability that $N = n$ is a lot bigger given that $U_1 \leqslant u$ than if we don't know anything about $U_1$. But to be sure, a rigorous calculation should be made.